# Critical Alert not disappearing

Tags: ios

I have implemented critical alerts in one of my app, which is working fine.
But I have a few questions about some of its behaviour.

- Critical alerts banner not disappearing unless clicked.
- Normal Notification's sound also not playing, when the critical alert
  banner is over the app

**Scenario**

1. Launch the app on iOS.
2. Login as a User A Send a normal alert to User A  (*Received alert with sound notifications*).
3. Send a Critical Alert
   message to User A (*Received message with sound notifications and
   don't read the urgent message*).
4. Again send a normal message to User A (*User A did not receive sound notifications until he read the critical alert*).

Please clarify if these are the default behaviour of Critical Alerts.

Comment: Isn't all of that simply what makes critical alerts critical?

Comment: @matt Regarding the first two questions, I can't find any document or link to confirm,  if these are the default behaviour of Critical alert. If you have any please provide me